# What happens on an unaligned MOVSD on various CPUs?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, sse2

Basically what the question says, if I execute a MOVSD that isn't 8-byte (or even 4-byte) aligned on various CPUs, what happens? Does it have a performance impact, can it segfault, etc.?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Volume 1 of the Intel Spec, Section 4.1

> 4.1.1 Alignment of Words, Doublewords, Quadwords, and Double Quadwords
>
> Words, doublewords, and quadwords do not need to be aligned in memory
>   on natural boundaries. The natural boundaries for words, double words,
>   and quadwords are even-numbered addresses, addresses evenly divisible
>   by four, and addresses evenly divisible by eight, respectively.
>   However, to improve the performance of programs, data structures
>   (especially stacks) should be aligned on natural boundaries when- ever
>   possible. The reason for this is that the processor requires two
>   memory accesses to make an unaligned memory access; aligned accesses
>   require only one memory access. A word or doubleword operand that
>   crosses a 4-byte boundary or a quadword operand that crosses an 8-byte
>   boundary is considered unaligned and requires two separate memory bus
>   cycles for access.

Under "normal" circumstances, an unalgined movsd will require 2 cycles to complete.

If you turn on alignment checking (in EFLAGS) then the CPU will raise an AC signal. It's primarily meant as a way to help you detect unaligned accesses.